# preload text to form field using URL query string

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink, query-string, textfield

I would like to generate a URL for [this webpage](https://registrar.uchicago.edu/records/diplomas/ce-diplomas-validation/) that prefills the two CeDiploma Validation form elements using a query string.

I have achieved the desired result for a validation form on a different university's webpage using the following URL: `https://cecredential.stanford.edu/cecredential/?credentialId=prefilledtext&nameLetter=AA`.  This produces:[image: desired prefilled form]

However, this method does not appear to work for the original site, i.e., the following URL with query string behaves in the same way as the URL without the query string: `https://registrar.uchicago.edu/records/diplomas/ce-diplomas-validation/?CeDiD=preilledtext&UserFirstTwoLetters=AA`

Being the utter html novice that I am, I don't understand why these two pages behave differently for these URL + query string.

**Update:** Strangely, it appears this method *does* allow me to prefill the text field for the UChicago page's search box, using `https://registrar.uchicago.edu/records/diplomas/ce-diplomas-validation/?s=pre`  This produces

[image: prefilled search field]

Still no luck with the CeDiploma form.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve and why? In general the behaviour you experience on the stanford page is part of the website's script code. If you don't have access to it you won't be able to prefill the input fields via URL. With more info about your use case we might help you with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> Being the utter html novice that I am, I don't understand why these two pages behave differently for these URL + query string.

One site has code which reads the query string and populates the form fields with data from it. The other does not.

> I would like to generate a URL for this webpage that prefills the two CeDiploma Validation form elements using a query string.

It would be a security problem if browsers could be made to populate form fields on arbitrary websites with just a URL. Unless the site provides you with a mechanism to do that (and it appears it does not): you can't.

Comment: Sorry for the belated comment.  "One site has code which reads the query string and populates the form fields with data from it."  Is it possible to elaborate/speculate on the possible mechanism for this?  Specifically, I'm confused by the fact that Standford form method specifies the "POST" rather than "GET" method, which suggests [(I think?)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) the form input is _not_ being appended to the URL upon submission.  In which case, it shouldn't expect to receive input via the query string I used, correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's because they are different websites with different frontends. They may have "CeCredential Trust" but that doesn't mean that they get the data in the same way. They are two separate organizations who can make websites how they choose. I've tried both sites switching the queries for both and they don't share any similarites except for "CeCredential Trust". You could try looking at the POST request data when you try to validate and go from there.

Comment: I understand they are different websites with different constructions (note the query strings I'm using are different based on how each one names their respective input text fields).  Unfortunately, I don't know what is meant by "looking at the POST request data" so I can't implement this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

## The desired result cannot be achieved

The query string for the Stanford site is being read by the server and returned as part of the response, i.e., **the Stanford server reads the fields you passed and modifies the webpage being returned so you see it pre-filled**.

As not all sites have been explicitly programmed to support this feature, you should not expect the other sites you mentioned to support it.

Alternate solutions include:

- Installing an extension like TamperMonkey in your browser and writing a script to fill the fields
- Reverse engineering the UChicago website, for example finding which URL it's querying after clicking the button, and then writing a script to impersonate a legitimate user and obtain the response directly without having to use the form.